# How many terms are required for harmonic series of degrees to "cover" a full $360^\text{o}$ circle?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, harmonic-numbers

This question accidentally came to my mind when reading about harmonic series. I've never been able to find an answer on the Internet. Consider $H_n$ which is the $n$-th harmonic number:
$$
H_n = 1 + {1\over 2} + {1\over 3} + \cdots + {1\over n}
$$

Not sure whether it's valid but suppose we have a circle which's full rotation is known to be $360^\text{o}$. Lets define the following series:
$$
S_n^\text{o} = (1)^\text{o} + \left({1\over 2}\right)^\text{o} + \left({1\over 3}\right)^\text{o} + \cdots
$$

Since harmonic series is divergent and its sum tends to infinity, then at some point we should have "covered" the whole circumference. If we now define an "$n$-th harmonic degree number" as $H_n^\text{o}$. Then we have to solve the following inequality for $n$:
$$
H_n^\text{o} \ge 360^\text{o}
$$

Please note that i'm not very familiar with series and only have basic calculus knowledge like limits, derivatives and Taylor expansion. Also I may have misused a lot of terms in this question, so please comment in order for me to improve it. Apart from that I'm basically interested in two things:

> 1. Is it valid to consider the harmonic sum of degrees rather than the sum of rationals?
> 2. If so what would be the way to find the index of $H_n^\text{o}$ such that the whole circle is "covered"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $H_n$ is close to $\log n$ if $n$ is large enough, you will have to take $n$ about $e^{360-\gamma}$, which is about $1.25\times10^{156}$. Here, $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

Comment: Indeed. Do you mind if I edit my answer, adding to it your suggestion?

Comment: whoa, that's a long way round. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Note that for large $n$, $H_n\sim \ln n$, so $\ln n\approx 360$ means that $n\approx 2.2\times 10^{156}$.

Comment: It is misleading to give so many significant figures! The approximation $H_n\sim \ln n$ is not nearly so precise.